# Jasmine doesn't load content of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jasmine

I try to access content of `iframe` in Jasmine tests

```
<iframe 
    src="http://www.*******.net/" 
    style="width:100%; height: 100%;" 
    class="frame"
    id="test-frame"
></iframe>
```

JS Code:

```
    describe('DOM of color elements checking', function () {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/units/js/fixtures';
    jasmine.getFixtures().load('frame.html');
    var fixtureIframe = readFixtures('iframe.html'); //here is iframe HTML
    $('.workspace__iframe-wrapper').append(fixtureIframe);

    $('iframe').load(function(){

       var body = $('.frame').contents().find('body');
       console.log(body);
    });
});
```

But content in `iframe` doesn't load.

Why is so happening?

Comment: Fragment revised, and updated code tag which was not visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solutions. Iframe load after starting tests. That's why my tests didn't see iframe. I've added beforeEach function in which wrote

JS

```
beforeEach(function(done){

   jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/units/js/fixtures';
   jasmine.getFixtures().load('frame.html');
   interval = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 15000;

   intId = setInterval(function() {

       $('#frame').load(function(){
           done();
       });
    }, 500);
});
```

And all are working!!!